# Vertical progress bar template .net

Tags: .net, progress-bar

I try to customize a .Net vertical progress bar (using Visual 2010), with the following code:

```
<ProgressBar Name="VolumeMeter" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="4,30,0,0" Value="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="10">
        <ProgressBar.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid Name="PART_Track" Background="Red">
                        <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator" Fill="Blue"/>                            
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Indicator" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Indicator" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Indicator" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Indicator" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ProgressBar.Template>
    </ProgressBar>
```

But, it doesn´t show the progress, What's wrong?

Comment: @Will:  That's not the problem this time.  :)  The key hint was "using Visual 2010".

Comment: @GregD: Whoops, thought I was clearing out an obsolete comment.  Don't see the difference.  Reading your answer now...

Answer (score 14):

The problem you might be running into is the result of a *breaking change* in .Net 4.0 that is a result of attempts to improve the performance of the WPF ProgressBar control.  (Something that, admittedly, it needed badly.)  Refer to [this issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20140717113835/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571674/issue-with-vertical-progress-bar-on-4-0-framework).

Short version:  In .Net 3.5 and earlier, you could author the progress bar and it was smart enough to adjust for vertical or horizontal orientation on its own.  In .Net 4.0, you *must* author your progress bar as though it was horizontal, then use a trigger and transform to rotate it into a vertical orientation when the orientation is vertical.  If you're using .Net 4.0 (which I suspect you are), this is why it's impossible for you to get your progress bar to behave the way you expect.

Sadly, this is *very* poorly documented in MSDN.  It's notable that the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638.aspx does not mention this, or address it in any way.  Likewise, the ProgressBar documentation itself (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) does not document this breaking change from the prior versions of the presentation foundation.  Thank goodness for the bug that was submitted, or I (too) would have thought I'd gone crazy.

The correct way to do this is now something like the following:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">

  <Border x:Name="Root">
    <!-- Visual tree goes here, be sure to include PART_Indicator and PART_Track -->
  </Border>

  <!-- Triggers must come after the Visual Tree so we can reference names. -->
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">

      <!-- Rotate the progressbar so the left edge is the bottom edge -->
      <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
          <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

      <!-- 
      Fix the render dimensions b/c what was the width is now height and vice-versa. 
      Note that we have to use {RelativeSource TemplatedParent} b/c {TemplateBinding}
      can't be used in a setter's value.
      -->
      <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Width"
       Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}"
       />
      <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Height"
       Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"
       />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Ouch, that's a bad breaking change.

Comment: Unfortunately this can wreak havoc on your fill gradient if you've not remembered to flip the start & end points.

Comment: Wonderful! But my Value starts at the middle of the progressbar... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

from your xaml, it looks like you are not binding it to anything.
you have to have something that tells it to update the progress, normally you would bind it to something on your datamodel, or have some method in your codebehind that does it.

Comment: yeh, we have all been young and inexperienced at one time or another. we don't hold that against him :)

Comment: hell no.  Learning about threads is like a rite of passage.  Almost as bad as tying vines to your ankles and jumping off a bamboo tower.

Comment: It´s WPF. I'm updating the value from the codebehind, using VolumeMeter.Value=XX, but, with exactly the same template, if I put Orientation="Horizontal" and swap the Height by Width values, it`s works....

Answer (score 0):

Something like:  `<Grid Height="{Binding CurrentValue}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">`