# Vertical Progress Bar Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I'm trying to implement a vertical progress bar in WPF and am having some difficulty. I'm following Greg D's answer from [Vertical progress bar template .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723950/vertical-progress-bar-template-net) but it's not working for me. I have tried both using a external style and inline and no luck. It's annoying as it seems a relatively simple answer.

Here's my `XAML`;

```
<ProgressBar Name="VolumeMeter" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="4,30,0,0" 
Value="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="10">
    <ProgressBar.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>

            <Border BorderBrush="Green" x:Name="Root" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid Name="PART_Track" Background="Red">
                    <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator" Fill="Blue"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">//Error Here

                <!-- Rotate the progressbar so the left edge is the bottom edge -->
                <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Width"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=Height}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Height"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=Width}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    </ProgressBar.Template>
</ProgressBar>
```

The error I'm getting is on the `<Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">` line, I'm getting;

> Cannot find the Template Property 'Orientation' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `TargetType` of the `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
```

or

```
 <Trigger Property="ProgressBar.Orientation" Value="Vertical">
```