# How to make a vertical progress bar?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a `ProgressBar` that is vertical rather than horizontal, I've tried changing the angle of the `ProgressBar` so it's vertical rather than horizontal, heres my code:

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="20" Height="30" Width="5" >
   <ProgressBar.Background>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.15999999642372131"/>
   </ProgressBar.Background>
   <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
       <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="0" CenterY="0"/>
   </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

However, the progress bar itself is from side to side rather than top to bottom. I've tried changing the `FlowDirection` but that only gives you the 2 options of `LeftToRight` or `RightToLeft`

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Is it a UWP app or 8.1 app? Consider editing your post to indicate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [ProgressBar.Orientation Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.orientation(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the orientation of a ProgressBar: horizontal or vertical.

Comment: I've also already tried this, for some reason `Orientation' is not a property for `ProgressBar` ?

Comment: @KTOV:- Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723950/vertical-progress-bar-template-net

Comment: I've tried adding `Triggers` to an edited copy of my `ProgressBar` style however it gives me an error asking if im missing an "assembly" or "reference"

Comment: Trigger is not supported in a windows phone project

Answer (score 3):

```
<ProgressBar RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
   <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
      <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
   </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

This works just fine for me.

Comment: Damn dude, I did say I don't want the progress bar to be flowing side to side

Comment: What do you mean by "flowing side to side"? I thought your "side to side" meant from left to right. No reason to be rude, I only tried to help.

Comment: Basically, I have my `ProgressBar` displaying vertically.. but the actual progress bar it self is flowing from left to right.. rather than bottom to top

Comment: But this solution works in my example just like that. Not only the progressbar element is vertically, but also the progressbar indicator is flowing from bottom to top. When giving the progressbar the value 50, it is filled (from bottom to top, vertically) a half.

Comment: You do know 90 degrees is a right angle ? So it would be displaying horizontally?

Comment: The standard progressbar is horizontal so by rotating it bei 90/-90 degrees it goes from this "_" to this " I ".

Comment: For some weird reason, mine's displaying horizontally at 90 :D

Answer (score 0):

`Orientation="Vertical"` in the `ProgressBar` tag and then in the rest of your code.