# Is there any way to make default progressbar into vertical one?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to have a progress bar that rather than going from left to right, fills from bottom to top. Is there any property or some way to convert the default progress bar provided by UWP controls into a vertical progress bar?

*edit
[image]

Look how when the rendertransform is applied -- progress bar flows out of the grid.

Here is the code!

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}" Padding="40">

    <Grid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Width="220" Height="200">
        <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                     Value="60">
            <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="0"/>
            </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
        </ProgressBar>
    </Grid>

    <Grid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Width="220" Height="200" Margin="40">
        <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                     Value="60">
            <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
            </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
        </ProgressBar>
    </Grid>

</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Still not fixed, did exchnaged the width and height!

[image]

Removed the margin and padding, still not working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a vertical progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416356/how-to-make-a-vertical-progress-bar)

Comment: @mjwills Indeed the question is the same, and I am aware of it! But none of the answers proposed works. There is no orientation property for ProgressBar and rotating the ProgressBar by 90 deg messes up with the flow of rectangle(as said in comments).

Comment: Have you tried to use `RenderTransform` ?

Comment: If you have placed `ProgressBa`r  vertically, you need to change the height and width(`Width="200" Height="220"`).

Comment: It's not working!

Comment: That reason is you used `Margin` in the second `Grid`.

Comment: What are you even telling! It's not working!

Answer (score 4):

UWP [`ProgressBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressbar) has no `Orientation` property. You could not use `progbar.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;` within UWP. If you want to place 
`ProgressBar` vertically, you could use [`RenderTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/transforms) to realize it.

```
<ProgressBar RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
             Maximum="200" 
             Value="50" 
             Width="200" 
             Background="LightGray"
             Foreground="Green"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" />
    </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Well, the thing is that I am using progress bar with variable width and height. You haven't used height property, try setting it to some value and putting it into a grid. Then see how the progress bar flows out of the control!

Comment: Yep, I know it , if you set height value, the progress bar will broaden. The reason  is that  `ProgressBar` placed vertically.  You can think of it as setting the height first and then placing it vertically.

Comment: So is there any way out? How can it be fixed?

Comment: I think there is a lack of communication going on! I want to achieve a certain functionality with progress bar that of a custom width as well as of height, and progress bar filling up from bottom to top. With your solution what is happening is that when render transform is applied the progress bar that is contained inside a grid now starts to abnormally flow out of it; which is totally undesirable. It's the reason I asked this question in the first place!

Comment: If put the progress bar inside a horizontal stack with a button on right. Will this render transform remove the spacing on the "right" when flip to -90 degree ?