# How can you make progress bar colors more vibrant?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

Doing this in C# WPF. To me it seems like the progressbar colors are really washed out; not vibrant:
[image]

Is this because they're animated? The color being called for the 'Leadership' progress bar is straight system color "Red". Is there a value that I can set that will make these colors 'pop' and be brighter and more intense?

Comment: that is a default ProgressBar template. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815175/wpf-progressbar-style (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4815280/1506454). try to create a new template with desired effects (or without unwanted)

Comment: It's important to note that different OSs might have different themes applied. The theme in the screenshot comes from a previous version of windows (looks like Windows 7 or 8). You can replace the template, but then your controls won't change to match the OS, which you might or might not want.

Comment: I ended up just throwing out the 'stock' ProgressBar and writing my own with different colors.