# WPF: change style of progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I change the style of a progressbar in WPF?
On Windows 10 it's a straight bar, but in win 7 it's splitted in many small blocks. I want to have the bar straight as on win 10, when the application is used on win 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF progressbar style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815175/wpf-progressbar-style)

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Comment: NOTE: There's a library called MahApps.Metro that styles all the controls to be the more modern metro theme.  You might want to look into that.  Source code is available on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just lookng for a property like 'ugly-block-spacing' which I can set. Or do I have really define the whole style new?

Yes, I am afraid you will have to re-define the entire `ControlTemplate` from scratch. You cannot override only a part of a `ControlTemplate`:

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the/41570242#41570242)

But you could copy the default `ControlTemplate` by right-clicking on a ProgressBar in design mode in Visual Studio on a Windows 10 computer, edit it as per your requirements and then use style i your application instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Progressbar has a property called Style, you could set it to your liking.

Comment: but then I need much code. I just lookng for a property like 'ugly-block-spacing' which I can set. Or do I have really define the whole style new?

Answer (score 0):

If you give Metro a try, you could use somthing like this:

```
<metro:MetroProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Value="50" Height="20"></metro:MetroProgressBar>
```

If you want to use the normal bar with Metro Style:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Value="50" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource MetroProgressBar}"></ProgressBar>
```

Same without Style:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Value="60" Height="20" Style="{x:Null}"></ProgressBar>
```

If you want to know more about Metro, you can find it [here](https://mahapps.com/controls/progressbar.html)