# Error:cannon impilicitly convert type 'System.windows.forms.progressbarstyle' to 'system.windows.style'

Tags: c#, wpf

This is WPF app.
I have this code in button :

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
```

but visual studio do not want to accept this two line :

```
 progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
```

This is error :

```
cannon impilicitly convert type 'System.windows.forms.progressbarstyle' to 'system.windows.style'
```

Here is other code:

```
 private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;     
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            executeFiles(this.myDir, this.myDirSecondStage, sqlConn);
            //worker.ReportProgress(15);
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("done!");
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
}
```

And here is in XAML code :

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="997,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" />
                    <Button x:Name="loadForShrinkLogButton" Content="Load Shrink" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="999,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Height="23" Click="loadForShringLogButton_Click"/>
```

Please some help! :)

Comment: please show declaration of progressbar also ...is it windows form progress bar ?

Comment: I edit my post :)

Comment: Where does progressBar1 come from, where do you build it?

Comment: @spootles - i need declaration of progressbar i.e. ProgressBar progressbar1 = new ProgressBar();....what is type of it have you used windows form progress bar etc.

Comment: I edit my post :)

Comment: You are trying to add an Winform style to your wpf progressbar?

Comment: Yep i try to add winform style in wpf.

Comment: @spootles well, you can't (at least in that situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is you are trying to assign Windows form value to WPF control , can you please check what is value form WPF progressbar.

Style property of WPF progess bar assign Style : [WPF progressbar style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815175/wpf-progressbar-style)

try this example : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38555/WPF-ProgressBar